# Calculating the probability that a value falls within a range in a normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics, normal-distribution

Example: what is the probability that an IQ score selected randomly falls between 80 and 110 inclusive?

I have tried calculating this in two different ways and got different answers. Which one is correct?

```
sum(dnorm(80:110, 100, 15))
# [1] 0.6722516
pnorm(110, 100, 15) - pnorm(79, 100, 15)
# [1] 0.6667508
```

Comment: Why don't you apply your two methods to a range where you know for a fact that the result should be 0, say limits of 100 to 100, and use that to determine "correctness"?

Comment: I would add that I didn't understand why you would use 79 rather than 80 in the second call to pnorm.

Comment: @42- I used 79 since I want the answer to include the probability of the score being 80. In other words I want the probability of the score being 80, 81, 82 ... 110. W.r.t. your other comment, I'm trying it out now.

Comment: Well 80 is just a point. It has no width. So I think you are going to be off by an amount `pnorm(80, 100, 15) - pnorm(79, 100, 15)`

Comment: @42- Sorry you're right. I was thinking about this as though the data were discrete, not continuous. I understand the error now, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the example says "falls between 80 and 110 **inclusive**", you should be computing

```
pnorm(110, 100, 15) - pnorm(80, 100, 15)
# [1] 0.6562962
```

In your first proposal you are approximating the definite integral by a finite sum, which introduces an error. In your second proposal, you are setting the lower bound to 79, so you would be including all the values equal or greater than 79, where you should be using 80.

Answer (score 1):

Your second approach is correct. The dnorm function returns the function value of the density function of the distribution at the given point. This means in general that the value can also be larger than one. On the other hand, the pnorm function return the integral from minus infinity up to the specified point. Since the normal distribution is a continuous probability distribution the integral under the whole curve is equal to one.
For more information on  the difference between probability density function and probability distribution function see: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175850/what-is-the-difference-between-probability-density-function-and-probability-d

Comment: this is a good explanation (but doesn't address the lower-bound-at-79-or-80 raised in comments and @DanielP's answer ...)